# Fine tuning Convolutional Neural Network with a learnable first layer

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-network, pytorch, finetuning

I have a classification task using grayscale images and I want to leverage from pretrained networks.

There are a lot of resources out there presenting how to [fine tune](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/finetuning_torchvision_models_tutorial.html) large neural nets like [resnet](https://huggingface.co/microsoft/resnet-50), alexnet, etc for our custom task (usually with less data). However, I stumble on the problem that I want to use Resnet learned features on data which is not RGB (3 channels). In fact, I'm using grayscale images. I thought about using an "embedder" as a first layer before resnet which can transform my `height x width x 1` image to a `224 x 224 x 3` resnet like input.

I wanted to know if there are works presenting this as an working approach (I couldn't get the right terminology to search for it). If so, is there a generic code to do so ?

```py
class NeuralNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,n_output):
        super().__init__()
        repr_size = 1024
        self.embedder = # The magic convolution code here that transform a 1 channel input to a 224 * 224 * 3 output
        self.backbone = resnet50
        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.Linear(repr_size,128),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(128,n_output),
            # nn.Softmax(),
        )
```

Comment: The "embedder" would be analogous to an image colorization network. As far as I know, image colorization is far from being solved in the general case.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to fine-tune ResNet with grayscale images directly because it was trained with color images from [ImageNet](https://www.image-net.org/download.php).

There are 5 solutions:

- [Convert grayscale images to RGB images](https://towardsdatascience.com/transform-grayscale-images-to-rgb-using-pythons-matplotlib-6a0625d992dd) staying gray, but the
  results would be poor because ImageNet is not based on grayscale
  images.

  import cv2 #OpenCV

  backtorgb = cv2.cvtColor(gray,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
- [Color grayscale images using OpenCV](https://pyimagesearch.com/2019/02/25/black-and-white-image-colorization-with-opencv-and-deep-learning/) and then use ResNet. It
  depends on the data you have. If the coloring works well, the results
  should be good with ResNet.
- [Train Resnet](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/modify-resnet-or-vgg-for-single-channel-grayscale/22762) (or any other CNN-based NN) from scratch using only
  your data with one gray channel. Therefore, you should have enough
  images.

class ResNet(nn.Module):

```
def __init__(self, block, layers, num_classes=1000):
    self.inplanes = 64
    super(ResNet, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=7, stride=2, padding=3,
                           bias=False)
    self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
    self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
    self.maxpool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1)
    self.layer1 = self._make_layer(block, 64, layers[0])
    self.layer2 = self._make_layer(block, 128, layers[1], stride=2)
    self.layer3 = self._make_layer(block, 256, layers[2], stride=2)
    self.layer4 = self._make_layer(block, 512, layers[3], stride=2)
    self.avgpool = nn.AvgPool2d(7, stride=1)
    self.fc = nn.Linear(512 * block.expansion, num_classes)
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 64, kernel_size=7, stride=2, padding=3,bias=False)
```

- Transform [ImageNet](https://www.image-net.org/download.php) to grayscale images and train ResNet with
  them and your data. This solution is the safest one but requires more
  training time.
- [Modify ResNet](https://towardsdatascience.com/transfer-learning-on-greyscale-images-how-to-fine-tune-pretrained-models-on-black-and-white-9a5150755c7a) with a Conv1 layer.
  Probably the smartest solution.